# Edit slides on slide show with dual monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, libreoffice

I want to connect a second monitor to my laptop and use Impress to show a slide on the second monitor. What I want to do is as the slide is showing to the second monitor, I could edit the next slide on my laptop screen and when I am ready, then show it to the second monitor.

I couldn't find a way to live edit them on slide show.